# How to extract data from a JSON array

Tags: c#

I need some guidance here, my code works ok until I try to map the front tyre width to a label!!

How do you access the JSON array code below?

Code below

```
public class DVLA
{

    public List<DVLAVehicle> cast { get; set; }

}


public class DVLAVehicle
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "make")]
    public string make { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "model")]
    public string model { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "year")]
    public int year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "frontTyres")]
    public frontTyres[] frontTyres { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rearTyres")]
    public rearTyres[] rearTyres { get; set; }


}

public class frontTyres
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int ratio { get; set; }
    public string rim { get; set; }
    public string speedRating { get; set; }
    public int psi { get; set; }
    public int loadIndex { get; set; }

}
```

var v1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(TyreDetails);

```
                lblmake.Text = v1.make;
                lblmodel.Text = v1.model;
                lblyear.Text = v1.year.ToString();

                lblwidth.Text = v1.frontTyres.Width;
```

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to say what error you're getting. I expect your problem is because `frontTyres` is an array so you need something like `v1.frontTypes[0].Width.ToString()`.

Comment: **v1.frontTyres** is an array of **fronTyres** objects. You can access an element of an array using [] operator. For example **v1.frontTyres[0].Width**. If you want to access it as **v1.frontTyres.Width**, then remove [] in DVLAVehicle.fronTyres